# react-redux nested component not ReactClass in parent?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am a bit new to react and redux, but made quite a lot of progress.
I am using redux connect to map state to props. Was working like charm, until I got this situation:

Parent component is using mapStateToProps, and here is the source code for it:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { NestedComponent } from './NestedComponent'

class ParentElement extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <NestedComponent/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  const { questions } = state
  return {
    questions
  }
}

ParentElement.contextTypes = {
    router: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ParentElement)
```

Here is the code for the nested element:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

class NestedComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <div> I am nested</div>
    );
  }
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  const { questions } = state
  return {
    questions
  }
}

NestedComponent.contextTypes = {
    router: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(NestedComponent)
```

When I try to show the parent element, I get this error:

> Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined,
>   boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a
>   ReactClass (for composite components). Check the render method of
>   `ParentElement`.

What am I missing / doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Import header file like this:-

```
import NestedComponent from './NestedComponent'
```

Without braces.

When a class is exported as a default then it is imported without braces because there is only one default class in a file but, when the class is exported without default you have to import it with braces because there can be more than one class with export keywords in a file (es6 conventions).

Comment: The answer is correct (+1), but would you like to [edit] your answer to explain why/how this fixes the problem?